# SAP Launchpad count on a static app tile?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

is there a way to set a $count on a static Tile or do something else like a count? The app does not have a odata-service it is just displaying some links, i wanted to display on the launchpad how much entrys are there

thanks

Comment: Well do you have a URL to some kind of RESTful Service which returns a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In static tile you won't get this functionality. You have to use dynamic tile and then you should have oData service url that will have list of data and then put $count to get the count.

Comment: Yeah, I know.. I mean i dont need really a oDataService but its the best I think